# How to override hook from themes functions.php which is defined in plugin

Tags: filters

I have defined a `apply_filters` hook inside `plugins_loaded` hook in  my custom plugin.

```
$post_singular_name = apply_filters( 'post_singular_name', 'Event' );
new Prefix\Post_Types($post_slug, $post_singular_name, $post_plural_name );
```

Now want to override the value of `post_singular_name` hook from themes `functions.php`. which is like following,

```
function singular_name_change( $v ) {
    return 'Portfolio';
}
add_filter('post_singular_name', 'singular_name_change');
```

But it is not affecting the hook. Expected value is `Portfolio` but still it is showing `Event`

Can you help someone how can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to debug, try to apply_filter on init hook instead of plugins_loaded.

Answer (score 1):

`plugins_loaded` runs before the theme is loaded, so it will never be able to filter something that happens on this hook from a theme.

If you want something to do with post type registration to be filterable you should perform the registration on the `init` hook. This is the usual hook for post type registration and it will allow themes to use the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Due to issue coming when the filters are applied. If the filter `post_singular_name` is being applied before the themes `functions.php` file is loaded or before the `singular_name_change` function is defined, then your filter in the theme won't have any effect.

Hok into `after_setup_theme`, you ensure that your filter is applied early enough in the theme loading process to affect the value of `post_singular_name` before it is used in your plugin.

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup');

function my_theme_setup() {
    // Define the filter within the theme's setup function
    add_filter('post_singular_name', 'Event');
}

function singular_name_change( $v ) {
    return 'Portfolio';
}
```